# Measuring how long a query is IDLE IN TRANSACTION (postgresql + Django app)

Tags: postgresql

When looking at `pg_stat_activity`, how can I tell whether the state `IDLE IN TRANSACTION` is transient?

Can the table's columns give that information to me (e.g. `xact_start` or `query_start`)? Btw, `waiting` is set to `f` for all these queries. Maybe that means they're not waiting on any locks, and so everything is fine?

I'm trying to ascertain how bad the `IDLE IN TRANSACTION` problem is on my app. There are lots of rows in `pg_stat_activity` with this state, but every time I re-query the table, there's new information. I need a more precise way to measure how long certain queries are `IDLE IN TRANSACTION`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A session that is "idle in transaction" can't have `waiting = true` because otherwise it wouldn't be "idle".

The difference between `current_timestamp` and  the timestamp in `state_change` should give you the time that the session was in "idle in transaction".

In general, a session that is just "idle" is not a problem. A session in "idle in transaction" might very well be a problem, as it prevents vacuum of cleaning up the rows that the transaction was using.

A short (a few seconds) "idle in transaction" is not a problem, only very long running  (minutes, hours) transactions that are not ended properly (and thus stick in "idle in transaction") are a problem.

---

With 9.6 you can force the server to disconnect long running "idle in transaction" sessions using the property [idle_in_transaction_session_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT)